# Android how to name tabs?

Tags: java, android, tabs

I would like to give my tabs names in my main.xml file. After a lot of searching i still havent found a working solution. if someone can provide a working solution/suggestion for this, all be it programatically or with xml i would be very thankful.

main_activity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private MyPagerAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(mAdapter);

        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mPager);
        mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final java.lang.String ARG_PAGE = "arg_page";

        public MyFragment() {

        }

        public static MyFragment newInstance(int pageNumber) {
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber + 1);
            myFragment.setArguments(arguments);
            return myFragment;
        }
    }
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = MainActivity.MyFragment.newInstance(position); //FRAGMENT fragment;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Fragment " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.lvlastuin.tabnav.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is there any wrong with programmatic way ?

Comment: In action bar or tab strip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

over ride this method in your pager adapter

```
@Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "tab1 name";
                case 1:
                    return "tab2 name";
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `MyPagerAdapter` class you have a

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Fragment " + (position + 1);
}
```

Which is generally where you set the names of the tabs. So when you instantiate it, just pass a collection of names you'd like to name the tabs